# Wake Other Computers from Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, windows, sleep-wake

Is there a terminal command within Mac OSX that will allow me to use WOL (Wake On LAN) to wake up other computers? Windows has wolcmd, is there an equivalent within OSX?

I am trying to wake a computer from my rMBP, within my network. My rMBP is connected via WiFi normally, but can also be connected via Thunderbolt GbE connector. The target computer is a Windows machine that I want to wake up before I connect to it using a remote desktop connection.

Comment: $ ~/bin/wakeonlan server-mac-address-here

Comment: @Buscar, On my mac (OS X 10.8.4), I get `-bash: /Users/Dygear/bin/wakeonlan: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Install the [wakeonlan](https://github.com/jpoliv/wakeonlan) package using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

`$ brew install wakeonlan`

(It's a Perl script for waking up computers via Wake-On-LAN magic packets.)

When installed, you can send a "magic packet" from your Terminal to any device using its IP (Internet Protocol) and MAC (Media Access Control) address.

Here's an example of a typical use:

`$ wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 -p 1234 01:02:03:04:05:06`

The scripts takes 2 arguments, the MAC address of the NIC, and an IP address.

> Note: The IP address argument is tricky and isn't what you'd think.
>
> For a NIC on your local subnet, use the broadcast-address of this subnet. (e.g. subnet 192.168.10.0 with netmask 255.255.255.0, use 192.168.10.255)

For example, I have a Synology NAS manually configured with the IP address of `10.0.1.100` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` and a router address of `10.0.1.1`.

**The correct IP address to use is *not that of the device*, but instead the *broadcast-address of the subnet*.**

Continuing on my example, I used the following command to successfully wake up my Synology:

`$ wakeonlan -i 10.0.1.255 -p 7 01:02:03:04:05:06`

*(Naturally, substitute the actual values of your device and network for your situation.)*

You can get more information from the wakeonlan man page, `man wakeonlan`, or a quick glossary of commands from `wakeonlan -h`.

Comment: I read somewhere, that it will only wake your mac from sleep, and not when it completely powered off. And maybe it also only works on LAN, not WLAN.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Cheers man

Comment: My broadcast-address isn't as clear as your example shows, so I used this site to determine: http://www.remotemonitoringsystems.ca/broadcast.php

Comment: Can this be used to wake a computer up from shutdown? It doesn't seem so. Is it possible to WOL a computer from cold boot by sending the magic packet? Apple Remote Desktop can already wake a computer up from sleep.

Comment: @MarkTomlin You asked for command line command, this is the correct answer.

Comment: A few years later, as in right now, I've accepted this as the correct answer as it clearly is.

Answer (score 66):

The `wakeonlan` command for command-line can be added to OS X using the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager.

Answer (score 23):

Python comes with OS X per default. So you could use this small Python 2 script to send the wake on lan package. Save it as `wakeonlan.py` or something you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Usage: wakeonlan.py <ADR> <MAC>     (example: 192.168.1.255 00:11:22:33:44:55)"
    sys.exit(1)

mac = sys.argv[2]
data = ''.join(['FF' * 6, mac.replace(':', '') * 16])
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(data.decode("hex"), (sys.argv[1], 9))
```

Use it like this:

```
python wake.py 192.168.1.255 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

Modify the IP address and MAC address accordingly. The IP address should be the broadcast address of the network.

For easy access you could make this script executable and add it to some directory in your path.

Comment: I like this solution with no installation required!

Comment: MacOS uses python3 by default now

Answer (score 4):

wolcmd is available for Mac: http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-for-apple-mac.aspx

[GUI version](https://itunes.apple.com/app/wake-on-lan/id412170664?mt=12) for $1.99, terminal version is free. Usage is just the same as its Windows counterpart.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Why download an unsigned opaque binary from some random web site, when you could just use the open-source program in the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

The RubyGems package which is stock on Mac, can also be used to install a wake on lan app.  Just use the `gem install wol` command in terminal.  It will install the activity in /usr/bin/local/wol.

This avoids having to install brew or package managers.  It accepts the same arguments as the wakeonlan examples above.

As an aside, the wol tool can wake a properly configured Synology NAS.

Comment: How is `gem` not a package manager too?

Comment: You are correct that gem is a package manager, but it was installed on macOS by default and did not require compilation or additional space beyond the tool itself.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working python3 version of @J.P. Petersen's solution, you need to replace the hex-decode component, e.g. with the solution mentioned here: [Decode Hex String in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys
import codecs

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: wakeonlan.py <ADR> <MAC>     (example: 192.168.1.255 00:11:22:33:44:55)")
    sys.exit(1)

mac = sys.argv[2]
data = ''.join(['FF' * 6, mac.replace(':', '') * 16])
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
decode_hex = codecs.getdecoder("hex_codec")
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(decode_hex(data)[0], (sys.argv[1], 9))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was struggling to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible to be installed through the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) package manager as well, but I don't have it installed, can't test it.

Comment: WakeOnLan *is* part of MacPorts, see https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=wakeonlan

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: can't upvote "@J. P. Petersen" or comment yet (don't have enough points), so an answer (late) will have to do.

@lacy is correct on Python3 now, but the script did need some mod, so here's what worked for me (since .decode no longer python3, and we need the MAC address to be bytes-like; also note simplified code and MAC address first argument, no colons); same use broadcast address (not IP address):

**$ pico wakeonlan3.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys
mac = bytes(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto(mac, (sys.argv[2], 9))
```

`$ chmod 775 wakeonlan3.py`

`$ python3 wakeonlan3.py 001451e6f3d1 192.168.0.255`

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to plop this out from the FreeBSD source code, for those not afraid and compiling a small c program.

[FreeBSD wake command source](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.sbin/wake/wake.c)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).